# Is there any way to fix my python code being stuck?

Tags: python

```
primeNum = []

def isPrime(y):
    i = 2
    while(i < number):  
        if number % i == 0: 
           return False
    i = i + 1
    return True

def printNum(x):
    k = 2  
    while k <= x:
        if isPrime(k):
            primeNum.append(k)
    k = k + 1        
     
printNum(number)

numOfPrime = len(primeNum)
sum = 0

j= 0
while j < numOfPrime:
    sum += primeNum[j]
j = j + 1  

print(sum)
```

When I run the code it just gets stuck on the input. I have tried everything but it doesn't give me an error unless I press CTRL + C then it will tell me Traceback.....

Comment: I think you've got some indentation problems with the incrementing lines.

Comment: Indentation is important in Python. If a line has the same indentation as the "while" below the "while" it will happen **after** the while-loop instead of in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the line `k = k + 1` in the function `printNum` was out of the while loop , making it an infinite loop,same goes for `i = i + 1` in `isPrime` and j `= j + 1` in the last loop, so i fixed it for you

additionally, the function `isPrime` had some bugs
it referred to `number` instead of `y` in a few places so I fixed that too

this should do the trick:

```
primeNum = []

number=10
def isPrime(y):
    i = 2
    while (i < y):
        if y % i == 0:
            return False
        i = i + 1
    return True


def printNum(x):
    k = 2
    while k <= x:
        if isPrime(k):
            primeNum.append(k)
        k = k + 1


printNum(number)

numOfPrime = len(primeNum)
sum = 0

j = 0
while j < numOfPrime:
    sum += primeNum[j]
    j = j + 1

print(sum)
print("end")
```

Comment: There are multiple places with the same problem.

Comment: I think you also have indentation problems. Have you tried your code?

Comment: I just tried yours but it is not doing what its supposed to be doing

Comment: thank you for the comments, right now the code is not stuck anymore , and the indentation is fixed in all of the function , i am working on making it work as OP intended :)

Comment: Thanks, I want to add all prime numbers less than a given number

Comment: I fixed it , if you could mark my comment as the answer i would appreciate it very much :)